# Generar un número de líneas precisas de binarios al azar con un bit de paridad

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero crear un script python que crea valores binarias en un fichero de tamaño variable con once atributos, el último sea un binario, 1 si el número de 1 es par. Intento hacer esto para crear un archivo [arff](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) para usarlo con el software [Weka](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)

Por ejemplo

```
$ python3 generacionBinarios

¿Cuentas lineas quiere usted ?

2
```

Y en el archivo de los resultados tendremos:

```
'1', '0', '1', '?','0', '1', '?','?','0','1','1'
'1', '0', '1', '?','?', '1', '?','?','0','0','0'
```

Intento el siguiente :

```
# Este programa escribe 1 línea de 11 enteros aleatorios,
# cada uno en el rango de 1-100 a un archivo de texto.

def main():

    lineNumber = input('Enter the number of lines you want')

    import random

    #Open a file named numbersmake.txt.
    outfile = open('numbersmake.txt', 'w')

    #Write 12 random intergers in the range of 1-100 on one line
    #to the file.
    for line in lineNumber :
        for count in range(11):
            #Get a random number.
            num = random.randint(0, 1)
            #Write 12 random intergers in the range of 1-100 on one line
            #to the file.
            outfile.write(str(num))
        outfile.write("\n")

    #Close the file.
    outfile.close()
    print('Data written to numbersmake.txt')

#Call the main function
main()
```

Y obtengo el siguiente cualquier sea el numero de lineas dado :

```
01101011010
```

Pero el último no esta vinculado con el numero de 1 generada.

Comment: Marine1 entonces ¿en realidad quieres generar una secuencia binaria de 10 elementos al azar siendo el elemento 11º determinado por el número de 1 que hay en los 10 anteriores? Es decir el último elemento no es al azar en realidad. ¿De donde salen los '?' de tu ejemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido lo que quieres en realidad es una secuencia binaria de 10 dígitos aleatorios en la que el último de ellos, el 11º es un bits de paridad (odd parity). si es esto puedes hacer algo así:

```
import random

def main():
    lineNumber = int(input('Enter the number of lines you want: '))
    with open('numbersmake.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for _ in range(lineNumber):
            ran_list = random.choices((0, 1), k = 10)
            outfile.write("{}{}\n".format("".join(str(bit) for bit in ran_list), 
                                          "0" if sum(ran_list) % 2 else "1"))
    print('Data written to numbersmake.txt')

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

[`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) fue añadió al lenguaje en Python 3.6, para versiones anteriores podemos usar `random.randint` usando un `for` adicional:

```
import random

def main():
    lineNumber = int(input('Enter the number of lines you want: '))
    with open('numbersmake.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for _ in range(lineNumber):
            ran_list = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(10)]
            outfile.write("{}{}\n".format("".join(str(bit) for bit in ran_list), 
                                          "0" if sum(ran_list) % 2 else "1"))
    print('Data written to numbersmake.txt')

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Siendo una salida algo como:

```
00100010010
00111101000
10001000111
00011111101
01100110001
11111001010
00011101010
00001000110
10001001101
10011001111
```

Comment: desafortunadamente obtengo `AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'choices'` Intento llamar `random as rdm` pero me da la misma error. Y como crear las comillas `'X'` con la `,` ? Intento hacer esto para crear un archivo arff para usarlo con el software [Weka](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)

Comment: @Marine1 ¿Que versión de Python usas? Se me pasó decir que `random.choices` se añadió en Python 3.6. Voy a editar la pregunta para añadir una versión para compatible con Python < 3.6.

Comment: Tengo la versión 3.5. Veré cómo moverme a 3.6